# iterate through a list of dicts and update quantities for items

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a list of purchases fetched from a json API that looks like this:

```
[{'quantity': '7', 'productUuid': '12345', 'unitPrice': 1234, 'name': 'apple'}, {'quantity': '7', 'productUuid': '12346', 'unitPrice': 4321, 'name': 'orange'}, {'quantity': '5', 'productUuid': '12345', 'unitPrice': 1234, 'name': 'apple'}]
```

What I'd like to do is get the following output where `productUuid` are compared and quantities added for the same `productUuid` to reflect the total sales of said product:

```
[{'quantity': '12', 'productUuid': '12345', 'unitPrice': 1234, 'name': 'apple'}, {'quantity': '7', 'productUuid': '12346', 'unitPrice': 4321, 'name': 'orange'}]
```

I tried the following, copying the relevant keys and values into a list for (I thought) easier manipulation, but it doesn't work and I feel there's probably a way easier solution to my problem.

```
def sort_products(json_list):
'''sorts by productUuid and merges indentical products'''
sorted_list = []

# copy lines to a list for easier sorting
for line in json_list:
    sorted_list.append([line['productUuid'], line['name'], line['quantity'], line['unitPrice']])

# sort
sorted_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

# merge
merged_list = []

for i, line in enumerate(sorted_list):
    merged_list.append(line)
    last_index = len(merged_list) - 1
    merged_list[i][2] = 0
    merged_list[i][3] = 0

    # copy if product not in merged_list and set 

    if line[0] == merged_list[last_index][0]:

        merged_list[last_index][2] = int(merged_list[last_index][2]) + int(line[2])
        merged_list[last_index][3] = merged_list[last_index][3] + line[3]

    else:

        merged_list.append(line)

        merged_list[last_index][2] = 0
        merged_list[last_index][3] = 0

        merged_list[last_index][2] = int(merged_list[last_index][2]) + int(line[2])
        merged_list[last_index][3] = merged_list[last_index][3] + line[3]
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it in the end by spending more time on it. I first created a list of uuids and then iterated through it to add the quantities.

```
def add_quantities(json_list):
    '''adds quantities for the same productUuid and returns a new dict with total quantities for each product'''

    # create a list to store uuids and another to store purchase dicts
    uuids = []
    list_of_totals = []

    for purchase in json_list:
        if purchase['productUuid'] not in uuids:
            uuids.append(purchase['productUuid'])


    # iterate through list of uuids against dict and add quantities for corresponding uuids

    for uuid in uuids:
        uuid_qty = 0
        totals = {}
        for purchase in json_list:
            if uuid in purchase['productUuid']:
                uuid_qty = uuid_qty + int(purchase['quantity'])
                unitPrice = purchase['unitPrice']
                name = purchase['name']
                totals.update({'productUuid': uuid, 'quantity': uuid_qty, 'unitPrice': unitPrice, 'name': name})

        list_of_totals.append(totals)

    return list_of_totals
```

any ideas to make this better are welcome.